# java: constructor in class cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, constructor, compiler-errors

When i try to compile my code with maven I get the following error:

```
constructor TripGuesser in class TripGuesser cannot be applied to given types
```

but in Eclipse (well actually FuseIDE) it does not raise an error!

my code is like this:

```
public class TripGuesser {
   private ArrayList<VehicleAbstract> vehicles;
   private DataAccessHandler dataAcces;
   private String stop_id;

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public TripGuesser(ArrayList<? extends VehicleAbstract> vehicles, DataAccessHandler dataAccess, String stop_id){
          this.vehicles = (ArrayList<VehicleAbstract>) vehicles;
          this.dataAcces = dataAccess;
          this.stop_id = stop_id;
    }
}


public class HelsinkiStopsHandler {
    ...
    ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicles = vehiclesPerRoute.get(routeAndDirectionId);
    TripGuesser guesser = new TripGuesser(vehicles, dataAccess, last_stopId);
    ...
}

public class Vehicle extends VehicleAbstract{
       ...
}

public abstract class VehicleAbstract{
       ...
}
```

I allready tried to call the constructor differently so my class HelsinkiStopsHandler looked like:

```
public class HelsinkiStopsHandler  {
    ArrayList<? extends VehicleAbstract> vehicles = vehiclesPerRoute.get(routeAndDirectionId);
    TripGuesser guesser = new TripGuesser(vehicles, dataAccess, last_stopId);
}
```

but still I get the same error.

I know there are a lot of familiar questions here but non of those answers work for me...

Java version: 1.7.0

Fuse IDE version: 6.0.0

Compiled with maven version: 3.1.0

Comment: You probably need to show real code. Also, note that Eclipse has its own compiler, and occasionally it gives different results from javac. The version of Eclipse and of javac are therefore relevant details too.

Comment: If you provide an SSCCE, someone is more likely to try to help you.  And, yes, version numbers are very important for investigating this  kind of problem.

Comment: why not use **B** consistently?  why do you need **? extends B** in the constructor?

Comment: I edited my question so now it includes real code and the version numbers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution...
It works when my code looks like:

```
 public class TripGuesser {
     private ArrayList<VehicleAbstract> vehicles;
     private DataAccessHandler dataAcces;
     private String stop_id;

     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
     public TripGuesser(ArrayList<VehicleAbstract> vehicles, DataAccessHandler dataAccess, String stop_id){
      this.vehicles = vehicles;
      this.dataAcces = dataAccess;
      this.stop_id = stop_id;
     }
 }


 public class HelsinkiStopsHandler {
      ...
      ArrayList<? extends VehicleAbstract> vehicles = vehiclesPerRoute.get(routeAndDirectionId);
      ArrayList<VehicleAbstract> vehiclesAbs = (ArrayList<VehicleAbstract>) vehicles;
      TripGuesser guesser = new TripGuesser(vehiclesAbs, dataAccess, last_stopId);
      ...
 }
```